# How to append link to <a> element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to add href to an a html element from class of another element. It might also be good to know that i am using Django.As well i dont want the second url to be visible, when the character is not selected yet. Firstly i have this list:

```
<ul>
  <a class="1" id="tablink">A</a>
  <a class="2" id="tablink">B</a>
...
</ul>
```

if list from the first ul is selected, i want the class of the list (example: A) to add to href element to all links in another ul:

```
<ul>
<a href="{% url id=id character= <!--here i want the number selected to be inserted--> %}">One</a>
<a href="{% url id=id character= <!--here i want the number selected to be inserted--> %}">Two</a>
...

</ul>
```

Thank you!
EDIT:
I have this code now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".tablinks").on("click", function(){
  var char = this.getAttribute("id");
  document.getElementById("subjects").href = "{% url 'subject_id' letnik_id=letnik_id classes_id=classes_id subject_id=" + char + " %}";

  });
</script>
```

But it has a problem:
It only works if i add attribute to element that i got with ID, so id doesnt work with

```
<a class="subjects">Hello</a>
doucment.getElementsByClassName("subjecs").href = ...
```

and the DJango url doesnt work (`"{% url 'subject_id' letnik_id=letnik_id classes_id=classes_id subject_id=" + char + " %}"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For giving the `anchor` a `href` use that:

```
$("#yourElement").setAttribute("href", "http://yourlink.com");
```

And if you're using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("yourElement").href="http://yourlink.com"";
```

You disable the second anchor with that code, change id and class value, you can't have the same `id`'s - `id` are unique values:

```
$(".tablink").on("click", function(){
  $(".tablink").css("display", "none");
  $(this).css("display", "block");
});
```

To add `href` when link is clicked simply add to the bottom of the above function:

```
$(this).setAttribute("href", "http://yourlink.com");
```

Comment: but if i use: document.getElementById("yourElement").href="http://yourlink.com"";
will "yourElement" be the only the one that is clicked, or all elements named "yourElements"

Comment: $(".tablinks").on("click", function(){
  var char = this.getAttribute("id");
  var subject = document.getElementsByClassName("subjects");
  subject.href = char
I have this code but it wouldnt set the href attribute

Comment: yourElement can be a `class` or and `id` or something else what can be an object. Check out [fundamental JavaScript knowlegde](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics).

Comment: Feel free to ask more!! And would be great if you can accept this answer and upvote for the help.. :)

Comment: felix your post helped me a lot!
I figured out a way to do this BUT it only works if i set href to element that i got with ID, If i want to get it by class name it doesn`t work :(

Comment: please edit your question above with the code you have written since now and I will look on it. Don't forget to vote :)

Comment: Did all of the above :D

Comment: can you explain better what the code should do? you want to add links to the anchors when clicking the link? what are these links? are they stored in an array or from where do they come?